# MySql error 1064, LIMIT 1 trouble using WHERE AND in MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-error-1064

Fixed the LIMIT 1 problem/ the page is now showing.

Basically it's an update profile page which checks to see if they want to use a username someone else has in the database

```
$exists = "";
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username from users WHERE username = '{$username}' AND id !={$id} LIMIT 1");
if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
    $exists .= "u";
}   
if ($exists == "u") echo "<p><b>Error:</b> Username already exists on someone elses account!</p>";
else {
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET email = '{$email}', username = '{$username}', realname = '{$realname}', tagline = '{$tagline}', bio = '{$bio}', facebook = '{$facebook}', steam = '{$steam}', youtube = '{$youtube}', steam = '{$steam}', youtube = '{$youtube}', twitch = '{$twitch}', playstv = '{$playstv}' WHERE id ={$id}";

if ($mysqli->query($sql)) {
        redirect_to("editprofiledata.php?msg=Updated Successfully");
    } else {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}</p>";
        exit();
    }
}
```

Hopefully I can check the usernames in the database versus username they've picked, and it will stop them if it matches someone else's but not their own.

At the moment it keeps displaying the following error, if I change the username it still does the same thing:

> Error, username already exists on someone else's account!

It could be because I'm also reading that information from the database to insert into the table to edit and maybe I'm not doing it the best way.

Comment: If `$_SESSION['user_id']` is not set/does not exist, then `...AND id !={$_SESSION['user_id']} LIMIT 1` will result in `...AND id != LIMIT 1`, which would cause the syntax error.

Comment: Ok thanks, Any idea how could I be losing that session ID then?

Comment: could it be i'm not posting that session ID in the submit?

Comment: Try removing the "LIMIT 1".

Comment: I've managed to get rid of that error, now the page displays even when you press update but it says! Error: Username already exists on someone elses account! ` $exists = "";
 $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username from users WHERE username = '{$username}' AND id !={$id} LIMIT 1");
 if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
  $exists .= "u";
 } 
 if ($exists == "u") echo "<p><b>Error:</b> Username already exists on someone elses account!</p>";
 else {
  $sql `

Answer (score -1):

`   # prepare data for insertion
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $username   = $_POST['username'];
    $realname   = $_POST['realname'];
    $tagline    = $_POST['tagline'];
    $bio        = $_POST['bio'];
    $facebook   = $_POST['facebook'];
    $steam      = $_POST['steam'];
    $youtube    = $_POST['youtube'];
    $twitch     = $_POST['twitch'];
    $playstv    = $_POST['playstv'];
    # check if username exists
    // u = username
        # insert data into mysql database
        $exists = "";
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username from users WHERE id !={$id} AND username = '{$username}' LIMIT 1");
    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
        $exists .= "u";
    }
    if ($exists == "u") { echo "

**Error:** Username already exists on someone elses account! Edit profile

";
    exit();
}
    else {
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET email = '{$email}', username = '{$username}', realname = '{$realname}', tagline = '{$tagline}', bio = '{$bio}', facebook = '{$facebook}', steam = '{$steam}', youtube = '{$youtube}', twitch = '{$twitch}', playstv = '{$playstv}' WHERE id ={$id}";

```
if ($mysqli->query($sql)) {
        redirect_to("editprofile.php?msg=Updated Successfully");
    } else {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}</p>";
        exit();
    }`
```